# post data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webstorm

I have a HTML file that includes:

```
<form method="post" action="localhost:3000/post">
   <input name="user[name]" type="text"/>
   <button type="submit">sub</button>
</form>
```

And in my node app.js file I write this lines for posting:

```
app.post("/post" ,function(req ,res ){
   console.log(req.body.user.name);
   res.send(req.body.user.name);
});
```

But I can't post that data.

After searching I found that I have to add this lines to node files:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

I install it with "npm install body-parser".But an error occurs.

How can I fix this?

Comment: error : Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately.

Comment: I think I've added answers for this problem, remove your line `app.use(express.bodyParser());` and whatever I've written in answer.

Comment: now what is the problem ?

Comment: after all this changes when I write something in that form and submit it ,the node don't receive the data and do nothing.

Comment: it's not going in `/post/` itself. Why do you have `action="localhost:3000/post"` I think you can have just `/post` if on same server or `http://localhost:3000/post`

Comment: When I use `action="/post"` instead of `action="localhost:3000/post"` ,browser return `404 not found` error ,and it show `"http://localhost:63342/post"`

Comment: it works with `action=http://localhost:3000/post` thank u so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOR SERVER PART**

If you've installed `body-parser` through `npm-install` successfully.

Adding these lines in you app.js should work

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

If gives warning like

```
body-parser deprecated urlencoded: explicitly specify "extended: true" for extended parsing
```

use following

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}));
```

**In Your Client**

In Your HTML you are saying that `action="localhost:3000/post"`.
I think this changed to

**/post** if you have to make request on same server

OR

**action="http://localhost:3000/post** If you are making request to some other server.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using express 4, bodyParser is no longer bundled with it.
So you have to change this line :

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

With this one:

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

You can find more informations and exemples here :

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Answer (score 0):

Try something liek this

To install try with sudo as I have found issues installing things without such at times:

```
sudo npm install body-parser
```

Then in your code if the above hasn't failed, something lie this:

```
var app = express().use(require('body-parser')());
app.post("/post" ,function(req ,res ){
   console.log(req.body.user.name);
   res.send(req.body.user.name);
});
```